# SQL Server stored procedure SELECT statement with few IF statement

Tags: sql-server

i have constructed my sql statemnet like the below way but i am getting error when try to compile. i know we can build it dynamically in string but like to know can we write statement like this way. please looking for suggestion.

```
INSERT INTO #tmpHierarchy (  
 JID ,  
 EntryDate ,  
 RefundDate ,  
 ActionBy ,  
 Comments ,  
 CID,  
 nLevel  
)    
SELECT 
   JID, EntryDate, RefundDate, ActionBy, Comments, CID, nLevel 
FROM 
   Hierarchy  
WHERE 1=1 
   AND 
IF @FromDate <> '' AND @ToDate <> ''
BEGIN
    Convert(varchar,EntryDate,112)>= @FromDate AND Convert(varchar,EntryDate,112) <= @ToDate
END

IF @ActionBy <> ''
BEGIN
    ActionBy=@ActionBy
END

IF @JID > 0
BEGIN
    JID=@JID
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have to build up a varchar with the query and then execute it:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql = 'INSERT INTO #tmpHierarchy (  
 JID ,  
 EntryDate ,  
 RefundDate ,  
 ActionBy ,  
 Comments ,  
 CID,  
 nLevel  
)    
SELECT JID,EntryDate,RefundDate,ActionBy,Comments,CID,nLevel FROM Hierarchy  WHERE 1=1' 

IF @FromDate <> '' AND @ToDate <> ''
BEGIN
    @sql = @sql + ' and Convert(varchar,EntryDate,112)>= @FromDate AND Convert(varchar,EntryDate,112) <= @ToDate'
END

IF @ActionBy <> ''
BEGIN
    @sql = @sql + ' and ActionBy=@ActionBy'
END

IF @JID > 0
BEGIN
    @sql = @sql + ' and JID=@JID'
END

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: without making dynamic sql can't we do it??

Comment: It may be a bit of fun to do it because of your convert functions - you don't want to get it executed if your value is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this where you combine the `IF` statements into the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT JID, EntryDate, RefundDate, ActionBy, Comments, CID, nLevel 
FROM Hierarchy  
WHERE 1 = 1 
AND (@FromDate = '' OR @ToDate = '' OR (Convert(varchar, EntryDate, 112) >= @FromDate AND Convert(varchar, EntryDate, 112) <= @ToDate))
AND (@ActionBy = '' OR ActionBy = @ActionBy)
AND (@JID <= 0 OR JID = @JID)
```